# Hyperlinks in S-columns?

Tags: tables, hyperref, siunitx

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{
            lmodern,
            babel,
            textcomp
           }
\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\newcommand*\EUR[1]{\mbox{#1\,\texteuro}}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tabular}{c}
    \hyperlink{Summe GK Vertrieb}{26{,}289}\\
    126
  \end{tabular}
  \hfill
  \begin{tabular}{S[table-format=3.3]}
    %\hyperlink{Summe GK Vertrieb}{26,289}\\
    126
  \end{tabular}\hfill

  \hypertarget{Summe GK Vertrieb}{Summe GK Vertrieb:}\[(20{,}719+1{,}25+4{,}32)\EUR{1000}=\EUR{26\,289}.\]

\end{document}
```

The result is the hyperlink within the c-column works. The Hyperlink within the S-column generates two errors.

Is there a way to use hyperlinks in S-columns?

Thank you for your help and effort in advance!

Comment: ```{\hyperlink{Summe GK Vertrieb}{\num{6626,29}}}\\``` avoids an error, but messes up the alignment.

Comment: I don't think currently this is possible (BTW: why don't use you `\num{...}` to format the numbers on the last line, you are already asking it to use Germen setup, so why do that by hand)

Comment: Hello @daleif! Sorry for the long delay! It's simple, `20{,}719` is shorter than `\num{20,719}` and `\num{20,719+1,25}` isn't allowed.

Comment: I do not agree, in addition `\num` gives a better semantic separation. What does `number+number` even mean in this context? Addition? then `\num` on each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution uses `\tablenum`.  Interestingly, just putting braces around it doesn't work.

```
\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{
            lmodern,
            babel,
            textcomp
           }
\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\newcommand*\EUR[1]{\mbox{#1\,\texteuro}}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tabular}{r@{,}l}
    \hyperlink{Summe GK Vertrieb}{26}&\hyperlink{Summe GK Vertrieb}{289}\\
    26&289\\
    126
  \end{tabular}
  \hfill
  \begin{tabular}{S[table-format=3.3]}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\hyperlink{Summe GK Vertrieb}{\tablenum[table-format=3.3]{26,289}}}\\
    26,289\\
    126
  \end{tabular}\hfill

  \hypertarget{Summe GK Vertrieb}{Summe GK Vertrieb:}\[(20{,}719+1{,}25+4{,}32)\EUR{1000}=\EUR{26\,289}.\]

\end{document}
```